# socket.io connection refused 400 (Bad Request) error

Tags: javascript, java, socket.io

I am using javascript as client like:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3700', {
    'reconnection delay': 2000,
    'force new connection': true
});
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected to port 3700');
});
```

Java Server Code:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setHostname("localhost");
    config.setPort(3700);
    final SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);
    server.addConnectListener(new ConnectListener() {
        public void onConnect(SocketIOClient client) {
            System.out.println("onConnected");
        }
    });
```

;

Getting below error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
http://localhost:3700/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJeUh3G Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

http://localhost:3700/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJUULaA Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

socket.io.js:1 GET http://localhost:3700/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJUUMoQ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Aren't you missing `server.start();`?

Comment: I have server.start() and listeners as well..